# I can't inject service and constant in same controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

I have a controller and I want to include a constant named myConstant from another file, and a service named myService:

```
app.controller('myController', ["$scope", "v3_0_0", function($scope, myConstant, myService, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $http) .....
```

Problem is that I the constant has to be included just after $scope, for it to work. Why is that? Furthermore, when I do this, I can't use the service?

Comment: What was the error you are getting ?

Comment: show us the constant code also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a constant, you have to declare it in your module :

```
angular.module('app').constant('myConstantName', 'value')
```

Same thing for service

```
angular.module('app').factory('myService', ['$http',function ($http) { .. }
```

After that you can include them in your controller :

```
app.controller('myController', ["$scope", "myConstant", "myService", function($scope, myConstant, myService ) { .. }
```